# Microsoft Graph ToDo task API

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

As I understand it, outlookTasks are deprecated in the Graph API (only available on the beta version) and will stop returning data in 8/2022. I am trying to use the To Do API but many properties of the item are missing (in particular owner and assignedTo).

For example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks/{id}
```

Returns (shortened):

```
{
    "id",
    "createdDateTime": "2021-04-20T02:42:07.6812715Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-04-20T03:02:12.6193785Z",
    "changeKey": "==",
    "categories": [],
    "assignedTo": "",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "importance": "normal",
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "owner": "",
    "parentFolderId": "=",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "status": "notStarted",
    "subject": "Test assign",
    "body": { },
    "completedDateTime": null,
    "dueDateTime": null,
    "recurrence": null,
    "reminderDateTime": null,
    "startDateTime": null
}
```

Whereas calling:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists/{listid}=/tasks/{id}

Returns:
{
    "importance": "normal",
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "status": "notStarted",
    "title": "Test assign",
    "createdDateTime": "2021-04-20T02:42:07.6812715Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-04-20T03:02:12.6193785Z",
    "id": "=",
    "body": {
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get those missing properties using Tasks or should I just use the beta outlookTasks and hope they introduce those properties to Task before outlookTask stops working?